# Не работает вывод в браузер PDF dompdf

Tags: php, php7, dompdf

При попытке выгрузить PDF в браузер с помощью $dompdf->stream('schet-16.pdf'); Выгружается невалидный PDF. При том, что загрузка pdf на сервер работает file_put_contents(**DIR** . '/schet-10.pdf', $pdf);

Версия PHP7.3

Сам PHP:

```
<?php
$html = ' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>bla bla bla!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
</body>
</html> ';

require_once __DIR__ .'/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
ob_clean();
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('schet-16.pdf');

$pdf = $dompdf->output(); 
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/schet-10.pdf', $pdf); 
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: А если `$dompdf->stream('/schet-16.pdf');`?

Comment: Не.. по прежнему невалидный  PDF. Там в самом PDF, какая то ерунда

<p>start</p><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  date(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Russia/Moscow', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in <b>/home/web/site_1/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php</b> on line <b>206</b><br />
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>

Comment: Оно вроде как `Moscow/Europe` называется.

Comment: Я на сервере вообще UTC поставил. Дело не в часовом поясе. Этот warning выводился в браузер. Но зачем это писать в начало PDF не понятно...
Если взять  PDF который открывается, то он   начинается c
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer

Comment: Я на сервере вообще UTC поставил. Дело не в часовом поясе. Этот warning выводился в браузер. Но зачем это писать в начало PDF не понятно...
Если взять  PDF который открывается, то он   начинается c
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer

Comment: Потому что сервер отдает файл в поток и тут же считывает его, у вас вначале вываливается ошибка, которую сервер сохраняет вместе в файлом. Избавьтесь от ошибки.

Comment: Поменял timezone  в php.ini. Вроде, все заработало